# AEM - How to create a template/ masking in textfield

Tags: adobe, aem, livecycle, livecycle-designer

How can I mask my textfield.

For example: 
 Upon initialization: The textfield should look like this
 **ISBN/______/__** -> where the underscores should contain the user input.

1. I have a default text which is **ISBN/    /**. ISBN/ cannot be deleted whenever I entered a text in textfield.
2. The text after ISBN/ should be a one letter character.
3. After the character it should accept four digits.
4. After the four digit character, there would be a slash.
5. After the slash it should only accept a two digit character.

I have tried this in the **Pattern palette** (display and edit tab) but it dont have any effect.**ISBN/** and **/** should not be deleted when the user types in the textfield.

Any suggestions? Also when the user types in it should start after **ISBN/**

[Textfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia7mD.png)

Comment: Is this possible in AEM designer?

Comment: Also I need this to be compatible in PDF and HTML viewer.